# Data entry form with formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I created a form for a phone book, it works, but when I enter the data, I would like the table I create to have black borders with the text in the center. If the phone sheet is active, it creates borders for me, but if I use the form by launching it from the search sheet, the border of the inserted cells is not created.

```
Dim numriga As Long

If txtCognome.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Cognome Obbligatorio!")
    txtCognome.Text = ""
    txtCognome.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

numriga = Sheets("Telefoni").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Rows(numriga).Columns("A:H").Borders
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = 2
 End With
Foglio3.Cells(numriga, 1) = txtCognome.Text
Foglio3.Cells(numriga, 2) = txtNome.Text
Foglio3.Cells(numriga, 3) = txtInterno.Text
Foglio3.Cells(numriga, 4) = txtCellulare.Text

txtCognome.Text = ""
txtNome.Text = ""
txtInterno.Text = ""
txtCellulare.Text = ""
txtCognome.SetFocus

MsgBox ("Inserimento eseguito con successo!")
End Sub`
```

Comment: ``With Foglio3.Rows(numriga).Columns("A:H").Borders``

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, but how can I align the inserted text to the center of the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify the `Rows` with the appropriate `Worksheet`.

To center the text, you can set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `xlCenter`:

```
With Foglio3.Rows(numriga).Columns("A:H")
    With .Borders
         .LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .Weight = 2
    End With

    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```